# Strange navigation controller behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, interface-builder, ios-simulator

I have a view that is pushed onto navigation stack like this:

```
FriendsDetailViewController *detail = [[FriendsDetailViewController alloc] init];
detail.user = selectedUser;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Inside a view controller, I have two elements: my custom controls view, that is a view with two buttons and a label inside, and a table view. I am setting constraints to them as shown:

```
-(void)setupView {
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];


    self.controlsView = [[ControlsView alloc] init];
    self.controlsView.player = self.player;
    self.controlsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.controlsView];
    [self setControlsViewConstraints];
    [self setTableViewConstraints];
}

-(void)setTableViewConstraints {
    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.controlsView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *leadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *trailingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[topConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint]];
}

-(void)setControlsViewConstraints {
    NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.controlsView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.topLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.controlsView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *trailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.controlsView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.controlsView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:30];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[top, leading, trailing, height]];
}
```

But by the end I get unexpected result.

[image]

Firstly, my custom controls view is black, although in code the background color is set to white. Secondly, custom controls view is situated just as I expected, but my table View is messed up. Somehow it does not sit on the bottom of my controls view.

I have other view controller without an embedded navigation controller, and the layout is just fine. [image]

It seems like I don't catch how navigation view is embedded in my view controller. I do the whole project without Interface builder, and this strange behavior is really confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS7, view controllers set scrollViews insets if there's a navigation bar, to make the content go behind the blurred bar (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)
so to fix your tableView you just need to set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO`

For the color of the other view, it's weird, but nothing in the code you posted changes the backgroundColor, are you sure you're setting it somewhere else?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to set backgroundColor of controlsView to white. Your solution works, thanks.